# Structuring users' favorites collection in Firebase and writing data to it

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I want to create a collection that looks like this:

```
{
    "favorites": {
        "userId1": {
            "favoriteId1": {
                "type": "movie",
                "name": "..",
                "...": "..."
            },
            "favoriteId2": {
                "type": "story",
                "name": "..",
                "...": "..."
            }
        },
        "userId2": {
            "favoriteId3": {
                "type": "movie",
                "name": "...",
                "...": "..."
            },
            "favoriteId4": {
                "type": "story",
                "name": "...",
                "...": "..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I'm also putting the details of the favorited movie/story is that each movie or story detail comes from the front-end. I know this is a bad practice but that's what the client wants.

I'm using this block of code to try to achieve what I want:

```
admin.database().ref("favorites").push().set({
    [userId]: {
        type: "...",
        name: "..."
    }
});
```

But this is, expectedly, creating a document that looks like this:

```
{
    "favorites": {
        "favoriteId1": {
            "userId1": {
                "type": "...",
                "name": "..."
            }
        },
        "favoriteId2": {
            "userId2": {
                "type": "...",
                "name": "..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, my question is, is the data structure, in the first block, the correct way to achieve what I want? Or is the data structure of firebase the correct one? What is the best practice to create, read, and delete favorited data?

I want to let users:

1. Add movie or story to their favorites
2. Remove movie or story from their favorites
3. Check all their favorites in their profile

Answer (score 0):

Since you call `push()` before passing in the UID, the push key in the result JSON is above the UID. If you want to have `.../$uid/$pushid/...` you can do:

```
admin.database().ref("favorites").child(userId).push({
    type: "...",
    name: "..."
});
```

So this pushes the new data under a node for the UID.

Comment: Thank you Frank, someone helped me solved this through putting the favorites as subcollection under users collection and I think this is the optimal solution. I guess I think way too much like how I build SQL databases! I'm not sure if I should keep this question or delete it.